# Azure DevOps query history for multiple WorkItems

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there any possibility to get history for multiple WorkItems using AzureDevops REST API?

I have found only following documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#list-work-item-revisions-(project-scoped) and there you can query only using single WorkItem ID. How about multiple IDs?

Some context to what I'm doing -- I have around 1k WorkItems and I need to check previous status they had before final one (e.g. last status is Closed, before it was either "In Progress" or "QA Failed"). Based on previous status I will need to perform some additional logic in my C# Code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will using [WIQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops) work? Either by establishing a query beforehand, then using the [Query by Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), or by issuing Wiql directly to the [Query by Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) endpoint?

Comment: @FrankAlvaro do you have example for this? Best things I've found after hours of googling is https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/235266/i-need-to-have-a-query-that-shows-all-work-items-t.html which has a very big drawback of requesting history for every single work item. If I have 1k of them, then there is a clear bottleneck

Comment: This was a "spot check" on my account, so no, I don't have any examples I'm afraid (which is why I only commented ).

Comment: Just looking again, The "Query by Wiql" direct API call will allow you to execute a query in the request body, but will **only** return a list of Work Item Ids. Per the note: "To get the full information, you need to perform two steps: (1) get the ID of the work items from a WIQL, and (2) get the work items via [Get a list of work items by ID and for specific fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list#get-list-of-work-items-for-specific-fields)."

Answer (score 0):

may be in this case you can write some sample application and iterate through all json response and save it. and later you can use json viewer tool for verification. because in one shot it will not show all workitems related history as well. you have to check for individual workitems one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the preview feature to create or use those queries with history instead of snapshot only. You can then query it with OData.